# Double Choco: Snaking

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

Rules of Double Choco:

- Divide the grid into rooms along grid lines.
- Each room contains two halves: one orthogonally connected area of shaded cells and one orthogonally connected area of unshaded cells. The two halves must be the same shape and size, although they can be rotated and/or mirrored compared to one another.
- A room can contain any amount of numbered cells. Numbers indicate the size of the half-room that that cell belongs to. For example, a 3 in a sheded cell indicates that that cell is part of a shaded area of size 3, which is one half of a room of size 6.

[image: Empty grid]
[Solve on Penpa+](https://tinyurl.com/yno9xgaf)

Comment: I seriously don't understand what the puzzle is.

Comment: @TonyEnnis Really sorry to hear that! The objective is to draw lines in the grid and divide the grid into rooms that satisfy all the listed properties. Maybe the [original rules](https://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/double_choco/) (with examples) are a little clearer? It's sometimes hard to find good wordings for all the requirements.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First

> [image]
>  Realisation that the 3 and 8 are not in the same cell; therefore this must be the shape outline.

Then

> [image]
>  Realisation that the 2 empty grids must go down; otherwise the dark 3 cannot be satisfied.

Breakthrough

> [image]
>  Realisation that the 8 pieces must go over to the dark section on the other side

Finshing

> [image]
>  Which in turn finishes the puzzle after simple logical deductions.